# install octave using brew error: make: *** [all] Error

Tags: macos, octave, homebrew

I am trying to install octave on a Mac using Brew, and run into this error:

==> make all

```
libtool: link: clang++  -o dldfcn/.libs/__voronoi__.so -bundle  dldfcn/.libs/dldfcn___voronoi___la-__voronoi__.o   -framework JavaVM ./.libs/liboctinterp.dylib -L/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.34/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2/../../.. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib /private/tmp/octave-vqLT/octave-3.8.0/liboctave/.libs/liboctave.dylib -lhdf5 -lz -lX11 ../liboctave/.libs/liboctave.dylib -lcurl -lcholmod -lumfpack -lsuitesparseconfig -lamd -lcamd -lcolamd -lccolamd -lcxsparse /usr/local/Cellar/arpack/3.1.4/libexec/lib/libarpack.dylib -lqrupdate -lfftw3_threads -lfftw3 -lfftw3f_threads -lfftw3f -lreadline -lncurses -lpcre -ldl /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib/libquadmath.dylib -lqhull -lm  -pthread -Wl,-dylib_file -Wl,/usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.8.0/lib/octave/3.8.0/liboctave.2.dylib:/private/tmp/octave-vqLT/octave-3.8.0/liboctave/.libs/liboctave.dylib   -pthread -framework JavaVM -framework vecLib

libtool: link: ( cd "dldfcn/.libs" && rm -f "__voronoi__.la" && ln -s "../__voronoi__.la" "__voronoi__.la" )

make[2]: *** [all] Error 2

make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I searched around but didn't find a solution. Could someone help me out?